# Sending jdwp tracking request failed!

Tags: android, ddms

I got this message in the DDMS:

> Sending jdwp tracking request failed!

I didn't understand the reasons.

Is there a problem using a stream to get the image from the Internet and use the TabBar cause the use of them in different application didn't launch this errors?

Answer (score 5):

I often get that message when Eclipse is running; however, I see it in the Console view and not DDMS. It happens when I close an emulator it was linked to (e.g. the LogCat view was showing its log messages). It's never stopped me from actually developing or being able to install applications onto another emulator though. Restarting Eclipse has also always fixed that message.

Comment: Evo 4G (had to use a third party driver) - fyi my app runs after restarting Eclipse. The same error continues to show on Eclipse though.

Answer (score 2):

This error is mostly result of incorrect permissions set for "ddms/android" scrips residing in "your sdk location/tools".

If you are getting only

```
Sending tracking request failed!
```

error then change the permissions assigned to "tools/android". 
To do that open the directory "your sdk location/tools/" using file browser. You should see a file named android, right click-> properties -> permissions tab -> select allow executing and program. [chmod].

If your error is

```
Sending jdwp tracking request failed!
```

then you need to apply same procedure described above for "your sdk location/tools/ddms"

Answer (score 1):

I was just helped with the LogCat problem. Open up your DDMS perspective, open the Devices view, and press Dump HPROF file button (red downwards pointing arrow). That get's my LogCat to work again.
Edit: **Actually, it seems like it's enough just clicking the device row in the Devices view.**

As for the console, press the Open Console button and try opening a new console, that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this by Cleaning Project under 'Project>Clean...'

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, after a close look my problem was very simple

i forgot the Internet permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file ;)

so the solution was simple too :)

i add this line to it

Comment: Could you mark this as the accepted answer to your problem then? That makes sure that people know you've solved the problem and makes it no longer show up in the "open questions" lists.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by giving full Control to the directory

```
[Path to Android_SDK]\sdk\build-tools\ -
```

You will find directory **android-4.4.2** then -

```
right click-> properties -> permissions tab -> Full Controll
```